# Allow non-owners to run script which changes protection settings in Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code which allows users to add editors to protected ranges:

```
    function addManager() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    var managerEmail= Browser.inputBox("Enter new manager's email address: ");
    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    protection.addEditor(managerEmail);  
   }
   Browser.msgBox("Access Granted To "+managerEmail)
   }
```

However, when any user that is not an owner attempts to run the code, they get an error message saying they do not have permission to edit protections (set by owners).

How can I:
1. Always run the code as the owner OR
2. Grant access to non-owners to edit protection ranges (set by owners)

Any leads/help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

How is this function being called?  I had this same issue recently with a spreadsheet I was trying to make.  I came to the conclusion that because the users do not have permissions, they will not be able to change permissions.

The work around I used was an `onOpen` trigger function.  A trigger function will only run as the owner of the sheet allowing you to set permissions.  The only thing to keep in mind that is there are only 3 types of triggers.  `onOpen` or `onEdit` / `onChange` (very similar).  Meaning that these triggers are the only times permissions will be able to be changed by the script.

I ended up ditching this method because the problem I had with the `onOpen` trigger is if someone was working in the sheet and a new user entered the sheet, it would change the permissions to the new user and mess up what the first user was doing.  Depending on your script this may not be an issue but I ended up doing an HTML web app as a ui to avoid interference between users.  The google sheet with the data is on the back end.

But anyways, here is an example how you could open the function with a trigger.

Running this function will install a custom trigger.  You can also manage your triggers in the Resources tab in script editor.

```
function InstallTrigger(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('addManager').forSpreadsheet(sheet).onOpen().create();  
}
```

Trigger will call function on open:

```
function addManager() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var managerEmail= Browser.inputBox("Enter new manager's email address: ");
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    protection.addEditor(managerEmail);  
  }
  Browser.msgBox("Access Granted To "+managerEmail)
}
```